# I want to get Affinity Interest from Google analytics api v4

Tags: json, node.js, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I put the tracking code of google analytics in my web Application, now i want to get the Interests of the user from Google analytics API, I am using Nodejs, here is my request's code and the JSON response I get.

```js
const dimensions_rows = [{
  name: 'ga:interestAffinityCategory'
}, ];

const date_filters = [{
  startDate: '7daysAgo',
  endDate: 'today',
}];
const req = {
  reportRequests: [{
    viewId: viewId,
    dateRanges: date_filters,
    dimensions: dimensions_rows,
  }],
};

analytics.reports.batchGet({
    auth: oauth2Client,
    requestBody: req
  },
  function(err, response) {
    if (err) {
      console.log('Failed to get Report');
      console.log(err);
      return;
    }
    // response.data is where the good stuff is located
    console.log('Success - got something back from the Googlez');
    console.log("responseee: ", JSON.stringify(response.data));
  }
);

//JSON response

{
"reports": [{
    "columnHeader": {
        "dimensions": ["ga:interestAffinityCategory"],
        "metricHeader": {
            "metricHeaderEntries": [{
                "name": "ga:visits",
                "type": "INTEGER"
            }]
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "totals": [{
             "values": ["0"]
        }]
    }
}]
}
```

Comment: And what is your question exactly?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Code working perfect, I received the JSON response, I want to get the Interest from that JSON, how should I?

Comment: I think you should reword your question then your issue is not related to the Google analytics api your question should be "How to read from a json object"